# How can I pass a data string to a programmatically loaded custom user control in C#

Tags: c#, controls, pass-data

I've written a Custom User Control which returns some user specific data. 
To load the Custom User Control I use the following line of code:

```
UserControl myUC = (UserControl).Load("~/customUserControl.ascx");
```

But how can I access `string user` inside the User Control `myUC`?

Comment: Oh please reword. This doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Excuse me English is not my main language. Which part should I reword?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's call your usercontrol "Bob"

If you Inherit from UserControl in Bob, then I guess it's safe to do this:

```
Bob b = (Bob).Load("~/customUserControl.ascx");
```

For the user part, I can't really follow what you want to do, is the "user" in the class were you create the "Bob" usercontrol and you want to set a property in the "Bob" usercontrol or is it the other way around?

For the first one you should create a property in your usercontrol.

```
class Bob : UserControl{
public string User { get; set;}
}
```

and then set it when after you create "Bob" instance.

```
b.User = theuser;
```

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your custom user control's name is "MyUserControl"

Try this code:

```
MyUserControl myUC = (UserControl).Load("~/customUserControl.ascx") as MyUserControl;
string result = myUC.user;
```

Comment: I made it the same way you suggested. But, because I want to load everything dynamically I'm not able put
<%@ Register Src="~/customUserControl.ascx" TagName="MyUserControl" TagPrefix="myUC" %>
at the top. And I thinks that's why I get an Error when I copy and paste your code.

Comment: Make sure your custom user control is derived from System.Web.UI.Control

Answer (score 0):

You will need to cast the loaded control to the actual type and use its public property:

```
MyUserControl myUCTyped = (MyUserControl)myUC;
myUCTyped.ThePublicProperty = "some value";
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks so far. My code is excactly the same as written above:

```
public partial class todo : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    private string mysecondteststring;
    public string setValue
    {
        get
        {
            return mysecondteststring;
        }
        set
        {
            mysecondteststring = value;
        }
    }
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // my code
    }
}
```

But I'm not able to create an Instance of poll, in my Web Service code. Do I forget something?

--> Forgot to add the `Reference` to the .aspx Page, where the user control is loaded dynamically. It's working now with normal .aspx Pages. 
Example code can be found [here](http://cid-5ccba32911d4030f.skydrive.live.com/self.aspx/Programming/dynamically%20add%20custom%20user%20controls.zip)

Does anyone of you know how user controls can be added in Web Services aswell, because the Reference Attribute isn't available there?